# If $S^1 \hookrightarrow X$ induces an injection of $H_1$, then $X$ retracts onto $S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, obstruction-theory

This is an exercise in Hatcher, section 4.3, exercise 3, page 419, on which I'm struggling.

> Suppose that a CW complex X contains a subcomplex $S^1$ such that the inclusion
>   $S^1 \hookrightarrow X$ induces an injection $H_1(S^1;\mathbb Z) \to H_1(X; \mathbb Z)$ with image a direct summand of $H_1(X;\mathbb Z)$. Show that $S^1$ is a retract of $X$.

I've been trying to use obstruction theory to solve this, but I'm stuck. Showing that $S^1$ is a retract is equivalent to showing there is a map $r : X \to S^1$ extending the identity $id : S^1 \to S^1$. By obstruction theory ($S^1$ is an abelian space, we can assume $X$ is connected), we need to consider groups of the form $H^n(X, S^1; \pi_{n-1}(S^1))$. The only nonzero such group is $H^2(X, S^1)$ (with integer coefficients).

Let $H_1(X) = H_1(S^1) \oplus M$. The long exact sequence in homology gives an exact sequence:

$0 \to H_2(X) \to H_2(X, S^1) \to H_1(S^1) \to H_1(X) \to H_1(X, S^1) \to 0$

Thanks to the hypothesis on $H_1$, we therefore have that $H_2(X) \simeq H_2(X, S^1)$ and $H_1(X, S^1) \simeq M$. By universal coefficients:

$$\begin{align}
H^2(X, S^1) & \simeq \mathrm{Hom}(H_2(X,S^1), \mathbb Z) \oplus \mathrm{Ext}(H_1(X,S^1), \mathbb Z) \\
& \simeq \mathrm{Hom}(H_2(X), \mathbb Z) \oplus \mathrm{Ext}(M, \mathbb Z) \oplus \mathrm{Ext}(\mathbb Z, \mathbb Z)\\
& \simeq \mathrm{Hom}(H_2(X), \mathbb Z) \oplus \mathrm{Ext}(H_1(X), \mathbb Z) \\
& \simeq H^2(X)
\end{align}$$

And this is where I'm stuck. There's an obstruction $\omega_2(id) \in H^2(X, S^1; \pi_1(S^1)) \simeq H^2(X)$, and I'd like to show that it's zero, but I don't know how. Could you give me some insight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot the initial step of the argument.  Your calculation shows that the map $H^2(X,S^1;\pi_1 S^1) \to H^2(X;\pi_1 S^1)$ is an isomorphism.  This means that the obstruction cocycle for constructing a map extending the one on $S^1$ is zero precisely when the obstruction cocycle for an unconstrained map, and it suffices to show that the latter is always zero.

Roughly, this *particular* obstruction is always zero, because this obstruction cocycle only depends on an existing choice of map from the $0$-skeleton.

More in detail.  Obstruction cocycles answer particular questions.  Given a map from the $s$-skeleton of $X$ to $Y$, we have such an obstruction cocycle measuring whether it's possible (given a current choice of map on the $(s-1)$-skeleton) to make some choice of maps on the $s$-cells to get a map which can be extended to the $(s+1)$-skeleton.  This is the obstruction that lives in $H^{s+1}(X, \pi_s Y)$, roughly because it's asking about whether the attaching maps for the $(s+1)$-cells can be made nullhomotopic in $Y$.

In your case, $s=1$.  You can take whatever map $X^{(0)} \to S^1$ that you are given and lift it up to a map $X^{(0)} \to \mathbb{R}$, and all such maps automatically have an extension to a map $X^{(2)} \to \mathbb{R} \to S^1$.

This pattern continues for Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces: the obstruction cocycle for a map $X \to K(G,n)$ depends only on a map from the $(n-1)$-skeleton, and all the maps from the $(n-1)$-skeleton to a $K(G,n)$ are nullhomotopic.  The obstruction cocycle is then the same as that for a constant map.  You only tend to get interesting obstructions when you've had the opportunity to make interesting choices on the lower skeleta.